# cell2table removes values from first column if string is a single character

Tags: matlab, cell

Suppose you have the following data:

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];

headers = {'force', 'mass', 'acceleration'};
units = {'N','Kg','m/s^2'};
```

Let's say I want to convert it to a table, where `headers` will be the `'VariableNames'`:

```
table_of_data = cell2table([units; num2cell(A)]);
table_of_data.Properties.VariableNames = headers
table_of_data = 
    force    mass    acceleration
    _____    ____    ____________
    N        'Kg'    'm/s^2'     
            [2]     [3]         
            [5]     [6]
```

Note that the first two columns of `A` are removed. This is because MATLAB treats the single character `N` differently than `'Kg'` and `'m/s^2'`. If I insert a space after `'N '` I get:

```
table_of_data = 
    force    mass    acceleration
    _____    ____    ____________
    'N '     'Kg'    'm/s^2'     
    [1]      [2]     [3]         
    [4]      [5]     [6]
```

How can I get a proper table, with all elements displayed without inserting a space `'N '`?

---

It's no problem to use a single character in `units` if I add more rows to the cell array, such as `[headers; units; num2cell(A)]`, so the following works:

```
table_of_data = cell2table([headers; units; num2cell(A)]);
table_of_data(1,:) = [];
table_of_data.Properties.VariableNames = headers
table_of_data = 
    force    mass    acceleration
    _____    ____    ____________
    'N '     'Kg'    'm/s^2'     
    [1]      [2]     [3]         
    [4]      [5]     [6]
```

How can I solve this without turning to cumbersome workarounds?

Comment: Why not store your units in `table.Properties.VariableUnits`?

Comment: What's happening is that it's implicitly converting the entire first column to `char`'s and `1` and `4` look like empty strings and for single chars, MATLAB removes the `''` around the string.

Comment: I've realized that. It can be seen quite easily if you try to write it to a dat-file (it can be seen in Notepad for instance). It would be nice to avoid it though :)

Comment: It's ugly looking, but probably the easiest way to get what you want is to replace units with `units = { {'N'}, {'Kg'}, {'m/s^2'}};`

Comment: @Suever. I'm writing this to a .dat file. `VariableUnits` aren't included when executing `writetable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely has to do with `table`'s internal representation of the data. It seems like what it does is tries to vertically concatenate the data in a column and if the concatenation succeeds then it uses an array, otherwise it stores it as a `cell` .

In the case of a single character `N` and the numbers, `1` and `4`, they can be concatenated without error; however, it converts them all to chars.

```
vertcat('N', 1, 4)
```

However, when you add the space, concatenation now fails

```
vertcat('N ', 1, 4)
```

And the output is displayed like a cell.

You have a few options:

1. Use `table.Properties.VariableUnits` to store the units rather than trying to incorporate the units into your table.

   ```
   table_of_data.Properties.VariableUnits = units;
   ```
2. Display the units in the column headers

   ```
   headers = {'force_N', 'mass_kg', 'acceleration_m_s2'};
   ```
3. Create a double-nested cell array to store all of the units, which explicitly causes it to be stored as a cell array internally.

   ```
   table_of_data = cell2table([num2cell(units); num2cell(A)])
   ```

Comment: I believe it's "prior to _creating_ it". I don't think it has anything to do with the actual displaying.