# Concatenating cell array of strings results in unprintable characters

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to take a cell array of positive integers and print them as a space delimited string. I have written the following function for that purpose:

```
function string = cell2str(cellArray)
    cellStrings = cellfun(@(i){[num2str(i) ' ']}, cellArray);
    string = strtrim(horzcat(cellStrings{:}));
end
```

When I run the statements one by one in the MatLab shell, this works as I would expect. But as soon as I call the function itself, the return value is an unprintable string, it just shows up as a square in the shell. What's going on here? (suggestions to improve the function welcome as well)

This is what it looks like when I run it (same result no matter how many characters I put into the input cell array):

```
>> cell2str({6})

ans =

□
```

Side note; Why can't I place this function in a subdir named 'private' as you usually do? When I do and call the function from the MatLab shell, I just get `Undefined function 'cell2str' for input argument of type 'cell'.`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, your function seems to work fine. Would you like to also provide a printout of how you call this in the terminal (including what input you give it) and the output it gives?

Comment: calling this function seems to work for me. it returns the string as expected. how do you call it? what's exactly your problem when put it in a private subdir?

Comment: as for the `private` subdir question, I'm assuming you're trying to access it from a script. "private" functions are only visible from other functions. (but we're already well into "guessing game" territory. Please rewrite your question to make it clear and leave no room for guesswork.)

Comment: You should show us `cellArray` (or the smallest subset of `cellArray` that can be used to reproduce this problem). It's very likely **very closely** related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298858/cell2table-removes-values-from-first-column-if-string-is-a-single-character).

Comment: For me; any and all inputs result in unprintable characters. But if it doesn't for anyone else, then I guess that is data as well. Then I suppose there is some environmental issue at my end.

As for the private subdir issue; then yes, I'm placing the function in a subdir named 'private'. But if those functions can only be called from other functions and not from the Shell, then that explains that.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. What does your `cellArray` look like? Only positive integers?

Comment: It will be only zeros and ones in it, but I tested it with {6}, {6 5} and {5 55 5} for instance and all of them yield the same result. But yes, only positive integers pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Ok, I can't reproduce this, so I can't help you I'm afraid.. I suggest you remove the semi-colons and see where the error occurs. Also, split `strsplit` into two parts, to see if you get problems with `horzcat` or `strsplit` (I'm assuming `horzcat`). And zero isn't positive :P

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. The thing is that the problem only occurs when I run the entire function. The statements by themselves return what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the integers are interpreted as ASCII. The following input reveals this:

```
cell2str({65 66 67 68 69})

ans =

A B C D E
```

A modified version avoids this problem:

```
function string = cell2str(cellArray)
    cellStrings = cellfun(@(i){sprintf('%d ', i)}, cellArray);
    string = strtrim(horzcat(cellStrings{:}));
end
```

And the problem with having the function placed in a subdir called 'private' was that you can only call functions placed there from inside other functions, not from the MatLab shell.

As an aside; a little more elegant solution with roughly equivalent execution time, would be this:

```
function string = cell2str(cellArray)
    strjoin((cellfun(@(i){num2str(i)}, cellArray);
end
```